# How do you convert a decimal date to a date field in a where statement?

Tags: sql, date, db2, ibm-midrange

I have a field that is a decimal date (YYYYMMDD). I need to find all
records that are a year or less old. Since date are so easy, I am
trying to do:

```
WHERE DATE(SUBSTR(CHAR(A.CPADDT),1,4) CONCAT '-' CONCAT 
      SUBSTR(CHAR(A.CPADDT),5,2) CONCAT '-' CONCAT
      SUBSTR(CHAR(A.CPADDT),7,2)) > CURRENT_DATE - 1 YEAR
```

This works great in the `SELECT` portion. When I put it in the `WHERE`
section I get "Selection error involving field *N."

Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the complete query you are using?, and the working query?. Also, what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: The RDBMS is the IBM i (or IBM midrange as the tag states).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Selection error involving field *N.` indicates you have an invalid date in your table.

Check the job log for a `CPD4019`.  The cause will include the relative record number of the bad date.

```
Message . . . . :   Select or omit error on field &10 member &1.            
Cause . . . . . :   A select or omit error occurred in record &5, record    
  format &7, member number &8 of file &2 in library &3, because of condition
  &6 of the following conditions:
```

---

You can also use **the** Jon Skeet's solution inline like so

```
WHERE A.CPADDT > YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - 1 YEAR) * 10000                
+ MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - 1 YEAR) * 100 + DAY(CURRENT_DATE - 1 YEAR)
```

and not have to worry about date conversion errors at all in addition to the other benefits.

Comment: This is where I was starting to think of going, however I did discover my problem. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

Fortunately, YYYYMMDD ends up following a natural order. So rather than parsing the records, why not just "format" the date from a year ago, and make a comparison with that?

It's unclear exactly where you're calling this from, and whether you could provide the logic there, but if not, and this is within a stored procedure, you can always put the logic there. Basically you want to have something like (pseudo-code):

```
CUTOFF = CURRENT_DATE - 1 YEAR
CUTOFF_NUMERIC = CUTOFF.YEAR * 10000 + CUTOFF.MONTH * 100 + CUTOFF.DAY
SELECT ... FROM A WHERE A.CPADDT > CUTOFF_NUMERIC
```

Apologies for not being able to give you the *actual* code - I'm not familiar with this dialect of SQL, and I'm far from a SQL expert anyway. Hopefully that's enough of a suggestion to get you going though. Note that this should help in terms of the performance, too - if you have an index on `CPADDT` then this query can use it easily, whereas your original attempt probably couldn't. Even if you *don't* have an index, a simple numeric comparison is likely to be cheaper than all of that formatting and parsing.

Comment: If they're on an ibm-midrange box, and they have six-character field names (and an 8-digit numeric date), then the most likely outcome is that they're using DB2 against 'legacy' tables.  Probably running from an RPG program (although more modern languages are possible); if so, there are several functions that will allow them to take a `date` type and translate it directly into a numeric format (and back again).  Which would (as you have pointed out) of course be the best option for indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the previous answers were good. In reality, I was a bad programmer and didn't make 100% sure the data was valid. There were a handful of "zero dates" where there isn't supposed to be any. After I removed those from the query it works.

```
A.CPADDT <> 0 AND DATE(SUBSTR(DIGITS(A.CPADDT),1,4) CONCAT '-' CONCAT   
    SUBSTR(DIGITS(A.CPADDT),5,2) CONCAT '-' CONCAT        
    SUBSTR(DIGITS(A.CPADDT),7,2)) > CURRENT_DATE - 1 YEAR
```

In this particular case, we are only including the data for self look-up if a person wants to see the status of their payment. I am probably not done with this as I am sure that there isn't any date validation on user input (the program is probably 15+ years old).

Comment: You should look into reversing this function, as the others have suggested.  This will allow you to use any existing indicies.  As well as not bombing when other `0` (or somehow otherwise invalid) dates are added.  And you should really look into getting this switched to an actual `date` column, which would allow you to avoid most of the hassle alltogether (and working at a legacy shop with similar vintage programs, I know that can be extremely difficult...).

Comment: I have been pondering how to handle the invalid dates. @JamesA's solution is probably best to avoid that. Especially since this is run in a background process that isn't really monitored.

Comment: In any event, do you really have to insert the hyphens (`-`)? Did you try simply `DATE(DIGITS(A.CPADDT)) > CURRENT_DATE - 1 YEAR`?

Comment: I thought I seen in the documentation that you can't do that. I could be wrong.